# CSV Date To Int SQL in SSIS

Tags: sql-server, csv, ssis

I am dealing with a transformacion in SSIS **from a CSV file to SQL table**

in the **CSV file** I have a column called Date with the format: **YYYY-MM-DD**

and my goal is to convert the values from that column to an **INT** value in an **SQL table** with the format: **YYYYMMDD**

any idea to make it possible? I was trying with a data conversion but I couldn't

Comment: So all what you need is eg 2017-10-12 become 20171012 using T-SQL?

Comment: Using SSIS, the source calues are in the CSV and they will be loaded into a SQL table with different formats

Comment: You can use T-SQL as below  select Convert(Int,convert(varchar(10), getdate(), 112)) as yourcolumn

Comment: Storing it as an int in your table sounds like a really terrible idea, by the way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Derived Column to transform and edit the date.

[image: Transformation]

[image]